# Custom Thread Pool - runnable called without calling start()

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to understand for custom thread pool implementation as explained in https://www.roytuts.com/custom-thread-pool-in-java/. After polling out of task queue as

```
while ((r = taskQueue.poll()) != null) {
          r.run();
       }
```

the code is directly calling run method without calling `start()` first. So, i am bit confused how runnable can be started without creating thread on runnable and then call start method? Can anyone please clear out my confusion where i am lacking the understanding. Thanks

```
class CustomThreadPool {
    // holds tasks
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> runnableQueue;
    // holds the pool of worker threads
    //private List<WorkerThread> threads;
    // check if shutdown is initiated
    private AtomicBoolean isThreadPoolShutDownInitiated;
    public CustomThreadPool(final int noOfThreads) {
        this.runnableQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        //this.threads = new ArrayList<>(noOfThreads);
        this.isThreadPoolShutDownInitiated = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        // create worker threads
        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfThreads; i++) {
            WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread(runnableQueue, this);
            thread.setName("Worker Thread - " + i);
            thread.start();
           // threads.add(thread);
        }
    }
    public void execute(Runnable r) throws InterruptedException {
        if (!isThreadPoolShutDownInitiated.get()) {
            runnableQueue.put(r);
        } else {
            throw new InterruptedException("Thread Pool shutdown is initiated, unable to execute task");
        }
    }
    public void shutdown() {
        isThreadPoolShutDownInitiated = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    }


    private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
        // holds tasks
        private BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
        // check if shutdown is initiated
        private CustomThreadPool threadPool;
        public WorkerThread(BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue, CustomThreadPool threadPool) {
            this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
            this.threadPool = threadPool;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // continue until all tasks finished processing
                while (!threadPool.isThreadPoolShutDownInitiated.get() || !taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    Runnable r;
                    // Poll a runnable from the queue and execute it
                    while ((r = taskQueue.poll()) != null) {
                        r.run();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CustomThreadPoolException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    private class CustomThreadPoolException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public CustomThreadPoolException(Throwable t) {
            super(t);
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is executing task.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        CustomThreadPool threadPool = new CustomThreadPool(2);
        threadPool.execute(r);
        threadPool.execute(r);
        threadPool.shutdown();
        // threadPool.execute(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread pool class calls `thread.start()` which calls `runnable.run()` by calling `thread.run()`. The last method is designed for threads initialized with runnable and can be called directly or via `start()`.

According to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()): *`start()`
Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.*

**EDIT**

Calling `runnable.run()` method simply **synchronously** executes runnable on the current thread (in which the method was called). In your case it is separate ones (which are created in CustomThreadPool). You can call `run()` directly in `main()`, which will synchronously execute the runnable on the main thread. Generally, the example is not breaking any concepts of using runnables, since it executes them on separate threads.

To make a long story short: **asynchronous** behavior is achieved by executing runnables on different threads. In scope of a single thread, calling multiple runnables' `run()` will execute them synchronously one by one.

Comment: actually, this is different runnable added to queue `threadPool.execute(r);` in main method. `thread.start()` starts worker thread not runnable one which is added in task queue

Comment: @user2269170 sorry for misunderstanding. Calling `run()` method of runnable is completely legal, and there is no strict need to create a separate thread for it. However, it breaks the concepts of Runnable, which state that it is a special interface for tasks, which need to be executed asynchronously. But in your case, these tasks are called on separate threads, since these thread are initialized in CustomThreadPool

Comment: @user2269170 I edited my answer, it may be not very clear, so let me know, if you still need help or clarification

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edits.I got your point but then what is the point of making it runnable? i have changed my code in local machine to execute non runnable tasks, it runs with the same behavior. But my doubt is , in what special situation runnable would have made difference?

Comment: @user2269170 in the example you provided, Runnable is used for convenience of passing tasks to the threads in the custom pool. This interface provides ability to wrap void functions or void lambda's.